# How to fix Admob "ads failed to load"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, admob

I have implemented a banner ads into my app, but the ads are not loading. What could be wrong

I followed the guide on https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start.
Test ads are loading fine, but on replacing the test adunit with my own adunit ads stop loading.

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
lateinit var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd
lateinit var mAdView: AdView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9198576040309894~2366427905")

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

    mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
    mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-9198576040309894/5170832446"
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
}

fun warmSelected(view: View){
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded) {
        mInterstitialAd.show()
        val warmIntent = Intent(this, WarmActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(warmIntent)
    } else {
        Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet."
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this demo ads keys? You should use demo keys.

Do you assign your key to xml? Change `MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9198576040309894~2366427905")` to `MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9198576040309894/5170832446")`

And add your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to your appId: `ca-app-pub-9198576040309894~2366427905`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"/>
```

I hope it will help you. Best regards